# How to update 'profile' contact programmatically in Android?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, contacts, user-profile

I want to edit the device main user's profile from within my application. So I used the `ContentProviderOperation` with `newUpdate` method to collect the changes and then commit them using the `ContentResolver` method's : `applyBatch`. Here is the code i wrote so far:

```
public ContentProviderResult[] updateProfile(Contact userProfile) {
        try {
            ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<>();
            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, Integer.valueOf(userProfile.id))
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, edtName.getText().toString().trim())
                    .build());
            return getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I am getting any run-time Exception but no change is commited! 
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it out, the problem was that I didn't know how to retrieve the User Profile `RAW_CONTACT_ID` to project on it on the `ContactsContract.Data` table.

My quick fix was by deleting the User Profile record and then create a new one. This is the code I used so far :

```
public ContentProviderResult[] createOrUpdateUserProfile() {
        ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
        int rawContactInsertIndex = ops.size();

        try {
            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.
                    newDelete(ContactsContract.Profile.CONTENT_RAW_CONTACTS_URI)
                    .build());

            getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
            ops.clear();

            //Create User Profile
            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Profile.CONTENT_RAW_CONTACTS_URI)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, null)
                    .build());

            //Create User Name
            if (!(edtName.getText().toString().matches(""))) {
                ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                        .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactInsertIndex)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, edtName.getText().toString())
                        .build());
            }

            if (!(edtHomePhone.getText().toString().matches(""))) {
                ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                        .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactInsertIndex)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, edtHomePhone.getText().toString())
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE, 1)
                        .build());
            }

            if (!(edtMobilePhone.getText().toString().matches(""))) {
                ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                        .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactInsertIndex)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, edtMobilePhone.getText().toString())
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE, 2)
                        .build());
            }

            if (!(edtWorkPhone.getText().toString().matches(""))) {
                ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                        .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactInsertIndex)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, edtWorkPhone.getText().toString())
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE, 3)
                        .build());
            }

            if (!(edtHomeEmail.getText().toString().matches(""))) {
                ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                        .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactInsertIndex)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS, edtHomeEmail.getText().toString())
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE, 1) // contact.numbers.get(0).type
                        .build());
            }

            if (!(edtWorkEmail.getText().toString().matches(""))) {
                ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                        .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactInsertIndex)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS, edtWorkEmail.getText().toString())
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE, 2) // contact.numbers.get(0).type
                        .build());
            }

            /*String completeAddress = edtStreet.getText().toString() + edtCity.getText().toString() + edtState.getText().toString()
                    + edtCountry.getText().toString();*/
            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactInsertIndex)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.STREET, edtStreet.getText().toString())
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CITY, edtCity.getText().toString())
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.REGION, edtState.getText().toString())
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.COUNTRY, edtCountry.getText().toString())
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.POSTCODE, edtZip.getText().toString())
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE, 1)
                    .build());

            if (!(edtSkype.getText().toString().matches(""))) {
                ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                        .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactInsertIndex)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Im.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Im.DATA, edtSkype.getText().toString())
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Im.PROTOCOL, 3)
                        .build());
            }


            ContentProviderResult[] res = getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
            return res;
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (OperationApplicationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

your code has a a bit error.

```
public ContentProviderResult[] updateProfile(Contact userProfile) {
    try {
        ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<>();
        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, Integer.valueOf(userProfile.id)) // Error is here
                .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, edtName.getText().toString().trim())
                .build());
        return getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

use for this line:

```
.withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, Integer.valueOf(userProfile.id))
```

this

```
.withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, getRawContactId(id))


public static String getRawContactId(String contactId)
{
    String res = "";
    Uri uri = ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI;
    String[] projection = new String[]{ContactsContract.RawContacts._ID};
    String selection = ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTACT_ID + " = ?";
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{ contactId };
    Cursor c = ContentManager.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);

    if(c != null && c.moveToFirst())
    {
        res = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.RawContacts._ID));
        c.close();
    }

    return res;
}
```